# Cannot achieve a distinct query result

Tags: hibernate

The result of this query has duplicate data :

```
@Override
    public List<MenuProfil> getMenuProfilAccessible(ProfilUtilisateur profil) {
        List<MenuProfil> retour = null;
        try {
            CriteriaBuilder builder = getSession().getCriteriaBuilder();
            CriteriaQuery<MenuProfil> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(MenuProfil.class);
            Root<MenuProfil> root = criteriaQuery.from(MenuProfil.class);
            criteriaQuery.where(builder.equal(root.get("profile"), profil.getId()));
            retour = getSession().createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw ex;
        }
        return retour;
    }
```

The model MenuProfil :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "menuprofil")
public class MenuProfil extends BaseModele {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "profile", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private ProfilUtilisateur profile;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "menu", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Menu menu;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public ProfilUtilisateur getProfile() {
        return profile;
    }

    public void setProfile(ProfilUtilisateur profile) {
        this.profile = profile;
    }

    public Menu getMenu() {
        return menu;
    }

    public void setMenu(Menu menu) {
        this.menu = menu;
    }

    public MenuProfil() {
    }

    public MenuProfil(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
       
}
```

I tried by specifying `criteriaQuery.distinct(true);` but nothing changes ! So how to remove duplicates in this case ?

Comment: You have to move the `@Id` to the field(s) which determine the uniqueness. JPA uses that annotation to distinguish a record identity fron another.

Comment: but it is already set on the `private int id;` field !

Comment: ID is an auto generated field different for each record!

Comment: @pheromix What exactly data are duplicated? `MenuProfil` ? It is not clear how it can be possible as I do not see any `@OneToMany` associations. Could you show generated sql?

Comment: @pheromix Try to use `builder.equal(root.get("profile"), profil)` instead of `builder.equal(root.get("profile"), profil.getId())`.